# Проверка wp_script_is и wp_style_is, не отрабатывает

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

В теме, functions.php использовал magnific-popup (js+css файлы).
Прошло некоторое время, понадобилось написать плагин/widget для ELEMENTOR, где он планируется использоваться.
Заглянул в консоль, JS и CSS подгружается дважды... Не порядок, начинаю делать проверку в плагине и functions.php через **wp_script_is** и **wp_style_is** и оказывается, что условие не отрабатывает, загружается и там и там (слепота). Делается всё по феншую (вроде), как у плагиноделов, но что бы не делал, загружаются дважды. Кто сталкивался?

Использовал вот такую конструкцию:

```
if ( ! wp_script_is( 'magnific-popup', 'enqueued' ) ) {
    wp_register_script( 'magnific-popup', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/magnific-popup.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'magnific-popup' );
}
```

Comment: handle (magnific-popup) поставьте одинаковый в теме и плагине, не будет загружаться дважды.

Comment: Да вроде они одинаковые... А что для них является отличием? Размер файла, содержимое, ссылка, CRC или что другое?

Comment: Да не файлы, а строки handle, 1 аргумент в `wp_register_script` и `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: Так я же пишу сразу - идентичны, проверка одинаковая, 'magnific-popup' в обоих случаях и файлы те же, только в разных местах. Единственное что вызывает сомнения, так это проверка 'enqueued', может другой надо статус проверять? ('registered' или например 'done')

Comment: Короче. я в functions делал wp_register_script и wp_enqueue_script, а в плагине прямое подключение wp_enqueue_script, как у большинства без регистрации. Как только сделал в 2х местах с регистрацией, проверка стала работать, но появился казус: JS подхватывается из плагина, что вроде по логике загрузки WP логично, а вот CSS по неведомой мне причине загружается из functions. Ищу дальше.

Comment: Всё разобрался. В плагине, в пути была ошибка, в связи с чем CSS просто не загружался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать регистрацию и включение в обоих случаях.

Буду дальше тестировать, но при использовании конструкции wp_register_script и wp_enqueue_script в обоих местах, у меня проверка стала работать корректно.

В плагине подключалось напрямую через wp_enqueue_script, без wp_register_script. Сам по себе он работает, но в связке с проверкой wp_script_is - не работало (подключался всегда).